# Is there any free XNA UI library?

Tags: user-interface, xna

I'm thinking of game in game user interface.

Comment: Possible dupe  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1561541/xna-and-gui-controls-eg-xaml-and-xna

Comment: @Joe Nope, I’m not referring to using XAML.

Comment: Are you saying you don't want XAML at all? It is a valid approach ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out XNAML:
http://msmvps.com/blogs/valentin/pages/xnaml-component.aspx

http://xnaml.codeplex.com/

> [The] engine is designed to run in a
>   pure Xna environement on all supported
>   device. My engine is extensible, you
>   can add your own controls, inherit
>   from base classes (such as Control or
>   Pane) to make your own behavior. The
>   compatibility with Xaml is complete.
>   Create your interface on Blend and
>   make a simple copy/past action to add
>   the Xaml file in your Xna project !
>   Extract a C# code from a Silverlight
>   project and just add it to your own
>   Xna project !

Comment: From what I can tell that project isn't open to public yet. Or am I just missing the download link?

Comment: updated the post to include a link to the codeplex site:  http://xnaml.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 2):

I would definitely check out the suggestions the The ZMan has put up on this [post](http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/t/15274.aspx).  There are lots of UI libraries in his post.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should look at [this list](http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/1891/9461.aspx):

I remember [Crazy Eddie](http://www.cegui.org.uk/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) as a good GUI builder.

Answer (score 1):

Probably a bare-bones approach (but anything XNA will be) would be the ScreenManager class as used by the Microsoft code samples. A guide to using it can be found in the [Game State Management](http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/game_state_management) documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is [XPF](http://red-badger.com/Blog/post/Introducing-XPF-e28093-A-Layout-Framework-for-XNA.aspx), an XNA-compatible library that seeks to replicate some of WPF's UI architecture. I use it myself - it's simple and elegant. It will be free for non-commercial use, with commercial pricing TBA.

(I haven't been able to load the XNAML website, but I'd guess XPF and XNAML have similar goals.)